# SharePoint Rest API shows error for Author/FirstName' is not valid

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, person-or-group

I have Rest API URL below:

```
https://DevSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items?$select=AuthorId,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,Author/Id,Author/EMail&$expand=Author
```

It is not working, it shows error:

**The query to field 'Author/FirstName' is not valid.**

[image]

I'm trying to get Author first and last name using REST API.

I have checked that there is items in list, everything is ok, still shows error

Comment: Hi, I tried rest endpoint its working on SharePoint 2013 on-premises ,Can you let us know for which Share Point are you trying?

Answer (score 1):

Refer below REST API URL :

```
https://DevSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$expand=Author&$select=Author/FirstName,Author/Id,Author/LastName
```